# "no matching function for call to" error when using constructor with two arguments

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm working on a textbook problem from Paul Deitel's "C++ How to Program", and I seem to be stuck on an issue.

We are asked to implement a constructor `DollarAmount` that takes two values (`dollars` and `cents`) and stores them as total pennies in a data member `amount`. Then we are asked to test our class with a simple program.

My program is as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "DollarAmount.h"               // Include the DollarAmount class header file
using namespace std;

int main() {
    DollarAmount amount1{1653, 45};     // $1653.45
    DollarAmount amount2{123, 6};      // $123.06
        
    cout << "amount1: $" << amount1.toString() << endl;
    cout << "amount2: $" << amount2.toString() << endl;
}
```

My class header file is:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

class DollarAmount {
public:
    DollarAmount(int64_t dollars, int cents) {   
        amount += dollars * 100 + cents;
    }
        
    void add(DollarAmount right) { 
        amount += right.amount; 
    }
        
    void subtract(DollarAmount right) {
        amount -= right.amount;
    }
        
    void addInterest(int rate, int divisor) {
        DollarAmount interest{  
            (amount * rate + divisor / 2) / divisor
        };
            
        add(interest); 
    }
        
    std::string toString() const {
        std::string dollars{std::to_string(amount / 100)};
        std::string cents{std::to_string(std::abs(amount % 100))};
        return dollars + "." + (cents.size() == 1 ? "0" : "") + cents;
    }

private:
    int64_t amount{0}; 
};
```

When my constructor only takes one argument, it works just fine. But as soon as I give it two arguments (`dollars` and `cents`), I get the following errors:

```
DollarAmount.h: In member function ‘void DollarAmount::addInterest(int, int)’:
DollarAmount.h:34:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘DollarAmount::DollarAmount(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   34 |         };
      |         ^
DollarAmount.h:14:5: note: candidate: ‘DollarAmount::DollarAmount(int64_t, int)’
   14 |     DollarAmount(int64_t dollars, int cents) {   // accepts dollars and cents
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
DollarAmount.h:14:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
DollarAmount.h:12:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr DollarAmount::DollarAmount(const DollarAmount&)’
   12 | class DollarAmount {
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
DollarAmount.h:12:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int64_t’ {aka ‘long int’} to ‘const DollarAmount&’
DollarAmount.h:12:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr DollarAmount::DollarAmount(DollarAmount&&)’
DollarAmount.h:12:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int64_t’ {aka ‘long int’} to ‘DollarAmount&&’
```

I have tried declaring both `dollars` and `cents` as `int`, as well as `int64_t` (my reasoning for making `cents` be `int` is because we only need a value 0-99 for it). I also tried a constructor of the form:

```cpp
DollarAmount(int64_t dollars, int cents) : amount{dollars * 100 + cents} {}
```

I am not sure why it says only one argument is being provided, or why the "no matching function call" error is occurring if I try and use two arguments, but not if I only use one argument.

Comment: In your `addInterest` member function, you are calling the constructor with a single argument, when you don't have a single argument constructor. What are you trying to do in that function exactly?

Comment: `DollarAmount interest{ (amount * rate + divisor / 2) / divisor };` is providing only one parameter to constructor, when there should be two.

Comment: Ah `addInterest` was in the original header file supplied by the textbook authors, because they wrote the program for a single argument. It seems I misinterpreted what that member function was doing. To answer cigien, the function takes an `int rate` as an interest rate and an `int divisor` which converts the `rate` input to the proper decimal form. I'll edit `addInterest` accordingly with two parameters! I'm new to c++ and am teaching myself so I make silly errors like this all the time.